# How to get the image manifest schemaVersion 2 from the docker registry REST API?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to write a web ui for the docker registry using python. I mainly do that, so I can learn alot about docker and i wanna have my own web ui.

I wanna display the uncompressed size for each iamge. As far as i know, it should be possible by fetching the manifest for a specific tag. I'm using the official docker registry from docker hub with the latest tag.

If i make a `GET http://docker.lan:5000/v2/my-image/manifests/latest`, I get the manifest, but only the schemaVersion 1, which is, if I saw it right, depricated.

```bash
{
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "my-image",
   "tag": "latest",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84506680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
      },...
```

How can i get the schemaVersion 2? It seems, that it has more details. I also tried to get each blob and adding each size to an integer, but that's just the compressed size and i wanna display the uncompressed size.

I tried to set the header for the GET to

```
{"Content-Type": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"}
```

or

```
{"Content-Type": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"}
```

as shown in [doc media types](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/manifest-v2-2/#media-types), but that did nothing, or I used that wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `Accept` header. Without that, the registry falls back to schema v1. The Accept header should be a list of media types you can receive, and there's both Docker and OCI media types:

> The client SHOULD include an Accept header indicating which manifest content types it supports. In a successful response, the Content-Type header will indicate the type of the returned manifest. The Content-Type header SHOULD match what the client pushed as the manifest's Content-Type. If the manifest has a mediaType field, clients SHOULD reject unless the mediaType field's value matches the type specified by the Content-Type header. For more information on the use of Accept headers and content negotiation, please see Content Negotiation.

https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#pull

For more on the Accept header, see the RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2